# Breadth First Search segfault

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a BFS that is supposed to solve a maze that currently only solves short mazes and returns a segfault for other mazes 
this algorithm is supposed to add to a vector a path as long as there are no junctions and if there are any junctions it is supposed to create two equally long vectors each following a single path.

```
std::vector<MazeNode> solveBFS(Maze &a_maze){

MazeNode * NextNode = a_maze.getFirstNode();
std::vector<MazeNode*> Final;
std::vector<MazeNode> Finals;
std::queue<vector<MazeNode*> > Qvec;



NextNode->setVisited();
Final.push_back(NextNode);
Qvec.push(Final);


while(!Qvec.empty() && Qvec.front().at(Qvec.front().size()-1) != a_maze.getLastNode()){
    cout << *Qvec.front().at(Qvec.front().size()-1) << endl;
    std::vector<MazeNode*> TempV = Qvec.front();
    MazeNode * Top = TempV.back();
    Qvec.pop(); 

    for(directions::nesw dir = directions::NORTH; dir < directions::WEST; dir = directions::nesw(dir + 1)){
           if(canTravel(Top->getDirectionNode(dir))){ 

            NextNode = Top->getDirectionNode(dir);
            NextNode->setVisited();
                NextNode->setVisited();

                TempV.push_back(NextNode);
                Qvec.push(TempV);
                TempV.pop_back();


           }
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < Qvec.front().size(); i++){

    Finals.push_back(* Qvec.front()[i]);
}
return Finals;
}
```

Comment: Please identify the line that will produce the segmentation fault.

Comment: What happens with `Qvec.front().at(Qvec.front().size()-1)` is `Qvec.front().size()` is zero? Are you sure that `Qvec.front()` will always be a non-empty vector? If you catch the crash in a debugger, where does it happen? What are the values of all involved variables? What are all the sizes of all the vectors and queues?

Comment: yes it will never be empty because it starts as 1 and as it enters the while loop more paths are entered into it I believe the error has something to do with the first for loop

Comment: Also, is `MazeNode` copy- or move-able?

Comment: `Qvec.front().at(Qvec.front().size()-1) ` -- All of that could be replaced with `Qvec.front().back();`

Comment: *yes it will never be empty because...* -- Are you assuming this, or did you actually debug your code?

Comment: thanks for all the comments the error was that I was trying < west in the first for loop instead of =< so I am assuming it was never checking west now it works!